# Can not get Docker container to load on localhost

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to get a container image to open on localhost (OpenVAS). I have done the following:

```
docker pull atomicorp/openvas
```

With the following being returned:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from atomicorp/openvas
Digest: sha256:------------------------------------------------(long sha hash)
Status: Image is up to date for atomicorp/openvas:latest
docker.io/atomicorp/openvas:latest
```

Afterwards, I try to run the image using the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 443:443 -e OV_UPDATE=yes --name openvas atomicorp/openvas
```

It returns the container id to the terminal (which is expected as that is what the option -d does. Afterwards, I go to my browser (Chrome) and attempt to open localhost on port 443. Nothing shows up on localhost page. (I typed localhost:443 in the browser). When I look at the docker processes, the container ID is present.

```
sudo docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                    PORTS                                   NAMES
0ac7d24c9227   atomicorp/openvas   "/bin/sh -c /run.sh"     7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes              0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   openvas
35825b7bfd96   armedu/mbed_sim     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 months ago    Exited (0) 6 months ago                                           cranky_margulis
f1d3dbcf4bbb   armedu/mbed_sim     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 months ago    Exited (0) 7 months ago                                           busy_galileo
a513e4e53d75   armedu/mbed_sim     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 months ago    Exited (0) 7 months ago                                           optimistic_carson
2492d538f000   armedu/mbed_sim     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 months ago    Exited (0) 7 months ago                                           cranky_ptolemy
fb770e031181   hello-world         "/hello"                 7 months ago    Exited (0) 7 months ago                                           exciting_feistel
```

I have tried to remove container ID, run the container again and it does not work. Any suggestions?

EDIT: As requested here is the log:

```
sudo docker container logs 0ac7d24c92270bf5434eb7c05f4adf0e7c977cb0108a248e061adfc6acd65a4c
Testing redis status...
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
Redis not yet ready...
Redis ready.
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (89.146.224.58): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (2a01:130:2000:127::d1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (89.146.224.58): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (2a01:130:2000:127::d1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [Receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (89.146.224.58): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (2a01:130:2000:127::d1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(125) [Receiver=3.1.2]
Restarting services

Checking for scanners: Done
Reloading NVTs
Rebuilding NVT cache... done.
Setting admin password
Checking setup
openvas-check-setup 2.3.7
  Test completeness and readiness of OpenVAS-9

  Please report us any non-detected problems and
  help us to improve this check routine:
  http://lists.wald.intevation.org/mailman/listinfo/openvas-discuss

  Send us the log-file (/tmp/openvas-check-setup.log) to help analyze the problem.

  Use the parameter --server to skip checks for client tools
  like GSD and OpenVAS-CLI.

Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.1.1.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=3.0.7.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /tmp/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /tmp/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
        OK: NVT collection in /var/lib/openvas/plugins contains 46373 NVTs.
        WARNING: Signature checking of NVTs is not enabled in OpenVAS Scanner.
        SUGGEST: Enable signature checking (see http://www.openvas.org/trusted-nvts.html).
        OK: The NVT cache in /var/cache/openvas contains 46373 files for 46373 NVTs.
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ... 
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 7.0.2.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 184.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 184.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database contains information about 46369 NVTs.
        OK: At least one user exists.
        OK: OpenVAS SCAP database found in /var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db.
        OK: OpenVAS CERT database found in /var/lib/openvas/cert-data/cert.db.
        OK: xsltproc found.
Step 3: Checking user configuration ... 
        WARNING: Your password policy is empty.
        SUGGEST: Edit the /etc/openvas/pwpolicy.conf file to set a password policy.
Step 4: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ... 
        OK: Greenbone Security Assistant is present in version 7.0.2.
        ERROR: Your OpenVAS certificate infrastructure did NOT pass validation.
        FIX: Run 'openvas-manage-certs -a'.

 ERROR: Your OpenVAS-9 installation is not yet complete!

Please follow the instructions marked with FIX above and run this
script again.

If you think this result is wrong, please report your observation
and help us to improve this check routine:
http://lists.wald.intevation.org/mailman/listinfo/openvas-discuss
Please attach the log-file (/tmp/openvas-check-setup.log) to help us analyze the problem.

Tailing logs
==> /var/log/openvas/gsad.log <==
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h00.27 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h00.32 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h00.32 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h00.32 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h01.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h01.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h01.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h02.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h02.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context
gsad main:WARNING:2021-05-19 01h02.02 utc:73: MHD: Error: received handshake message out of context

==> /var/log/openvas/openvasmd.log <==
md   main:   INFO:2021-05-19 01h00.20 utc:116: update_or_rebuild_nvt_cache: Rebuilding NVT cache
base gpgme:MESSAGE:2021-05-19 01h00.20 utc:116: Setting GnuPG dir to '/var/lib/openvas/openvasmd/gnupg'
base gpgme:MESSAGE:2021-05-19 01h00.21 utc:116: Using OpenPGP engine version '2.0.22'
md   main:   INFO:2021-05-19 01h00.22 utc:116:    Updating NVT cache.
md   main:MESSAGE:2021-05-19 01h03.35 utc:150:    OpenVAS Manager version 7.0.2 (DB revision 184)
md manage:   INFO:2021-05-19 01h03.35 utc:150:    Getting users.
md   main:MESSAGE:2021-05-19 01h03.35 utc:151:    OpenVAS Manager version 7.0.2 (DB revision 184)
md manage:   INFO:2021-05-19 01h03.35 utc:151:    Modifying user password.
md   main:MESSAGE:2021-05-19 01h03.36 utc:222:    OpenVAS Manager version 7.0.2 (DB revision 184)
md manage:   INFO:2021-05-19 01h03.36 utc:222:    Getting users.

==> /var/log/openvas/openvassd.dump <==

==> /var/log/openvas/openvassd.log <==
[Mon Jul 23 23:24:16 2018][8912] openvassd 5.1.1 started
[Mon Jul 23 23:24:35 2018][9114] Client not present
[Wed May 19 01:00:22 2021][68] openvassd 5.1.1 started
[Wed May 19 01:00:58 2021][131] Client closed the communication
```

I don't want to guess but it seems as if I can not connect to OpenVAS somehow.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the container cannot run the updates with the following error:

```
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (89.146.224.58): Connection timed out (110)
rsync: failed to connect to feed.openvas.org (2a01:130:2000:127::d1): Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

This [issue comment](https://github.com/mikesplain/openvas-docker/issues/162#issuecomment-728971960) makes me believe that the mirror might have changed. You can either exec into the container and run the command from the comment or create a separate image with this change and use that.